# Get key name from Map

Tags: ruby

I have this Ruby structure

```
AMOUNT_LIMITS = {
    qqpay: {
      cny: { min: 10_00,     max: 10_00_00 }
    },
    online_banking: {
      cny: { min: 10_00,     max: 50_000_00 },
      thb: { min: 10_00,     max: 500_000_00 },
      idr: { min: 10_000_00, max: 50_000_000_00 },
      myr: { min: 10_00,     max: 10_000_00 }
    },
    bank_payout: {          
      thb: { min: 350_00,    max: 350_00 },
      idr: { min: 50_000_00, smax: 50_000_00 },
      myr: { min: 50_00,     max: 50_00 }
    }
```

How I can get the currency type from the map? For example:

```
AMOUNT_LIMITS[transaction_type.to_sym].sample
```

I need only the key for example `cny` as a String.

Comment: What do you mean by "`cny` as a string"? Do you mean, for example, that you want to get `{ min: 10_00, max: 50_000_00 }` if `transaction_type == "online_banking"`? (But that's not a `String`?...)

Comment: What result would you expect if `transaction_type == "bank_payout"`? `nil`? What about if `transaction_type == "not_a_real_type"`? Please be specific about what your question is.

Comment: ok, let's skip the part as a string. How I can get the key?

Comment: I expect to get only the random key `thb` for example.

Comment: Ohhhh, right... So `cny`, `thb`, etc represent currencies, and you want a **RANDOM** currency for a given transaction type?

Comment: `AMOUNT_LIMITS[transaction_type.to_sym].keys.sample.to_s`?

Comment: By the way, this is far beyond the scope of your question, but if this is needed in an application then perhaps it would be better to store this data in a database, not a hardcoded hash (which is possibly not a great data structure choice anyway, due to awkward conversions like the above!). For example, you could have a `transaction_types` table, an `currencies` table and a `currencies_transaction_types` JOIN table that contains the `min` and `max` values shown above. Doing this would make any sort of data fetching much easier to follow/edit/extend compared to the above.

Comment: e.g. You could do something like: `TransactionType.find_by(name: 'qqpay').currencies.order('RAND()').first.name`

Answer (score 1):

To get a sample with weights:

```
AMOUNT_LIMITS.values.flat_map { |h| h.map(&:first) }.sample.to_s
#⇒ 'thb'
```

To get any currency with the same probability, use `uniq` in the middle:

```
AMOUNT_LIMITS.values.flat_map { |h| h.map(&:first) }.uniq.sample.to_s
#⇒ 'cny'
```

---

To get currency based on transaction type:

```
AMOUNT_LIMITS[:onlibe_banking].keys.sample.to_s
#⇒ 'cny'
```

Comment: I made a mistake. I need to get the currency based on the transaction type. Can you show me updated answer please?